# How to correctly include a javascript file into html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run a script through HTML but I am having some problems. I searched online and found how to do so, however the issue is that even if I correctly type the path of the .js file, it seems to add some strange characters before it.

This is in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fractalTest/fractalTest.js"></script>
```

I expected this to work but when I open index.html in google chrome and inspect then look under the elements tab, this "â©fractalTest/fractalTest.js" is replacing "fractalTest/fractalTest.js" in the path of the file. I believe this is whats causing the error but I do not know how to fix it!

Comment: What is your file structure?

Comment: Could you be using another symbol, like smart quotes, instead?

Answer (score 3):

> ...it seems to add some strange characters before it.

That usually means that the file is saved with a [byte-order mark](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) (BOM) of some kind, but isn't being sent with the correct `charset` for that byte-order mark.

Be sure that the server is configured to serve the files with a specific encoding (UTF-8 is a good choice), and that you save the files using that encoding (in your text editor, etc.). It's also usually best not to include a BOM on UTF-8 files (although it's valid, some tools don't handle it well).

---

Side note: No need for the `type` attribute. [The default](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-script-type) is JavaScript.